# Extracting values from pandas dataframe based on list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I'm trying to filter a pandas dataframe, which contains a column with news headlines (column name 'title'), based on whether each headline contains any of the company names from a list ('co_names_list')

I've already tried the following

## attempt 1

```
sp500news = pd.DataFrame()
for i in raw_news_2.index:
    for j in co_names_list:
        if j in raw_news_2.loc[i,'title']:
            sp500news = sp500news.append(raw_news_2.iloc[i])
            print(sp500news)
```

## attempt 2

```
sp500news = raw_news_2.loc[raw_news_2['title'].isin(co_names_list)]
```

[Sample Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skJ1i.png)

Comment: Please share a sample of the dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do what you want:

```
df[df.title.str.contains('|'.join(co_names_list))]
```

What you are doing with this is checking for each sentence in `title`, if any of the words in `co_names_list` are contained in the sentence. That is done by joining all words in the sentence with a `'|'`, which acts as an `OR` operator.